# How can I enable a button on field change using bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wanting to add and remove `bootstrap` `addClass` and `removeClass` based on the value of my textbox. Can anyone give me some advice on how to accomplish this?

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bckelley/htsmveeh/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitted").click(function () {
        var text = $("#answer").val();
        var comparingText = "7";
        if (text == comparingText) {
            $('#submitted').removeClass('disabled');
        }else{
            $('#submitted').removeClass('btn-primary');
            $('#submitted').addClass('btn-warning');
        }
    });
});

<span>6 + 1 = </span><input style="width: 50px;" type="text" id="answer" value="" placeholder="" style="display: block;" />
<input class="btn btn-primary disabled" type="submit" id="submitted" name="submitted" value="Submit" />
```

**EDIT CHOSEN SOLUTION**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitted')
        .toggleClass('btn-danger disabled');

    $("#answer").keyup(function () {
    var text = $(this).val();
    var comparingText = "7";
    var valid = text == comparingText;

        $('#submitted')
            .toggleClass('btn-primary', valid)
            .toggleClass('btn-danger disabled', !valid);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#answer").keyup(function () {
        var text = $(this).val();
        var comparingText = "7";
        var valid = text == comparingText;

        $('#submitted')
          .toggleClass('btn-primary', valid)
          .toggleClass('btn-danger disabled', !valid);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $.change() event listener:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  // listen for change to #submitted element
  $('#answer').change(function(){
// things to do on change

if ( $('#answer').val() === '7' ){
  // things to do if the #answer text is 7
  $('#submitted').removeClass('disabled');
} else {
  // things to do if the #answer text is not 7
 $('#submitted').addClass('disabled');
};
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

or simply you can change your code to :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#answer").keyup(function() {
    var answer = $("#answer").val();
    var comparingText = 7;
    if (answer == comparingText) {
    $('#submitted').toggleClass('btn-primary').toggleClass('btn-danger disabled');
    } else {
    $('#submitted').toggleClass('btn-primary',false).toggleClass('btn-danger disabled',true);
    }
  });
});
```